# Scaling a canvas on Android

Tags: android, canvas

I'm developing an Android project using canvas and I have a scaling problem. to make it more simple I'm going to use an example.

Let's supposed my view is : width 1300px and  height 800px  , I'm putting a canvas inside that goes a static width 1300px but the height is a variable. If my canvas is > 800px so the canvas will goes out of the view so I was trying to use canvas.scale() but I don't know how to calculate the exact value to put inside the scale !

Any ideas ?

Comment: I am not sure if I got your question correctly. Are you unsure about how much you want to set yScale factor when calling `canvas.scale(xScale, yScale)` . Also do you always want your canvas size to be equal to width and height of device?

Answer (score 0):

My personally, I think you should create a new `Canvas`. To do that you should resize your bitmap first. Using the below method to compute the scale between size of view and size of bitmap.

```
public static float computeScale(float w1, float h1, float w2, float h2) {
    if (w1 > 0 && h1 > 0 && w2 > 0 && h2 > 0) {
        return Math.max(w1 / w2, h1 / h2);
    }

    return 1;
}
```

So the scale and the new bitmap width, height will be calculated by the below code:

```
float scale = computeScale(viewWidth, viewHeight, bitmapWith, bitmapHeight);
if(scale > 1){
    int newWidth = Math.round(bitmapWidth / scale);
    int newHeight = Math.round(bitmapHeight / scale);
}

// The code for resizing the source bitmap with the newWidth and newHeight.
// Bitmap newBitmap = ...;
```

Finally, you use the new bitmap to create a new `Canvas`.

```
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(newBitmap);
```